# Сохранить массив структур в бинарник

Tags: c, файлы, структуры

Нужно сохранить массив из структур:

```
struct MyMessen {
        char Login[257];
        char Password[257];
        char SessionID[257];

        unsigned char Operation;

        int Answer;
};
```

В виде бинарного файла.

Массив динамический, но известна его длина

Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Массив динамический, но известна его длина

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каковы дополнительные требования к сохранению? Нужно ли/можно ли сохранять неиспользованное пространство в строках?

Лобовое бинарное сохранение тривиально: одним махом шлёп весь массив в файл

```
void save_array(FILE *f, const struct MyMessen a[], size_t n)
{
  fwrite((const char *) a, sizeof *a, n, f);
}
```

и готово!

Comment: Если массив большой, а носитель медленный, запись может прерваться сигналом. TL;DR: у вас нет никаких проверок на ошибки.